# Is there a way to have local option values for Blocked variables?

Tags: scoping

Like I can set local attributes for a variable,

```
Attributes[WolframAlpha]
Block[{WolframAlpha},
    SetAttributes[WolframAlpha,Listable];
    {WolframAlpha["western europe",{"WolframParse","WolframResult"}],
    Attributes[WolframAlpha]}
]
Attributes[WolframAlpha]
```

> {Protected, ReadProtected}
>
> {{HoldComplete[EntityClass["Country", "WesternEurope"]],
>   EntityClass["Country", "WesternEurope"]}, {Listable}}
>
> {Protected, ReadProtected}

How do I set local option values for a variable?

```
Options[WolframAlpha]
Block[{WolframAlpha},
    SetOptions[WolframAlpha,TimeConstraint->60];
    {WolframAlpha["western europe","WolframResult"],
    Options[WolframAlpha]}
]
Options[WolframAlpha]
```

> {AppearanceElements -> Automatic, Asynchronous -> False,   ExcludePods
>   -> None, IgnoreCase -> False, IncludePods -> All,   InputAssumptions -> {}, Method -> {}, PodStates -> {},   PodWidth -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> 30}
>
> During evaluation of In[xx]:= SetOptions::optnf: TimeConstraint is not
>   a known option for WolframAlpha.
>
> {EntityClass["Country", "WesternEurope"], {}}
>
> {AppearanceElements -> Automatic, Asynchronous -> False,   ExcludePods
>   -> None, IgnoreCase -> False, IncludePods -> All,   InputAssumptions -> {}, Method -> {}, PodStates -> {},   PodWidth -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> 30}

---

Following the suggestion of @Rom38 tried:

```
Options[WolframAlpha]
Block[{$WolframAlpha=WolframAlpha},
    SetOptions[$WolframAlpha,TimeConstraint->60];
    {$WolframAlpha["western europe","WolframResult"],
    Options[$WolframAlpha]}
]
Options[WolframAlpha]
```

> {AppearanceElements -> Automatic, Asynchronous -> False,   ExcludePods
>   -> None, IgnoreCase -> False, IncludePods -> All,   InputAssumptions -> {}, Method -> {}, PodStates -> {},   PodWidth -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> 30}
>
> {EntityClass["Country",    "WesternEurope"], {AppearanceElements ->
>   Automatic,    Asynchronous -> False, ExcludePods -> None, IgnoreCase
>   -> False,    IncludePods -> All, InputAssumptions -> {}, Method -> {},    PodStates -> {}, PodWidth -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> 60}}
>
> {AppearanceElements -> Automatic, Asynchronous -> False,   ExcludePods
>   -> None, IgnoreCase -> False, IncludePods -> All,   InputAssumptions -> {}, Method -> {}, PodStates -> {},   PodWidth -> Automatic, TimeConstraint -> 60}

Note: This is not really inheriting the definition but seems like the actual pointer to the original variable because the option value is changed globally outside the scope. This only works when an explicit local variable is created by using `Module` instead here. (Updated: Sorry even `Module` doesn't work here! Maybe there is no way to copy the definition of a builtin symbol to another variable without referring to the original definition without using `Internal` functionality.)

Comment: The simplest way is making duplicates of the variables. Let's say you have `a,b,c`, so do `{a,b,c}={a1,b1,c1}` and share (globalize) the second set of them.

Comment: Use ``Internal`InheritedBlock``. The only reason you're even getting an `EntityClass` result from the regular `Block` is because it evaluates after it exits the `Block`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you! I was a bit suspicious since I saw only `Listable` appearing in the `Attributes` rather than `{Listable, Protected, ReadProtected}`. I didn't know about this hidden `Internal` scoping construct. If you want credit please provide as an answer and I will accept it. Moreover this `InheritedBlock` will remain in future versions or it could be deprecated or removed?

Comment: @user13892 it’s been around forever so it’s not going anywhere